# How to store images in database without using PHP script

Tags: database

How can i store images in database without uploading them using PHP script. I mean is there a way that i can put the images on apache server directory and then store their index like path to the database?

Comment: How do you expect the image to be transferred to the server directory if not via PHP or another backend technology?

Comment: well...i had a thought in mind that the images would be put somewhere on the server directory, So i thought if there is a way that i can put the images on apache server directory somewhere and then do further code?

Comment: Do you want (A) your users to upload images or do you want (B) to upload images yourself and use it in your application?
(A): Your question should be more specific, the possible answers are way too broad
(B): This is basic knowledge and an answer would also be too broad. There are plenty of tutorials on how to create a website including file upload to a web server.

Comment: No...I don't want anything with the users....i only want to use it in my android application...it's just for backend...there's no website or anything.....

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your images to your server and store the path to your images as a text in your database or you can store your images base64-encoded.
If you store the path you need to ensure that the images are accessible from your android app.

- Image to base64 String (e.g. JavaScript): [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)
- Display base64-image-string: [Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

Comment: How can i upload my images to my server?

Comment: and store the path in database?...that's what i want to know

Comment: Imho this is too basic for SO, but may you have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Upload_files_to_a_web_server or search for it on google/bing/whatever. There are plenty of (good) results.